# Angular selectRootElement Works With App Not With Test

Tags: angular, attributes, angular-renderer2

My Angular application requires that data be passed to the root component on the page in the following manner:

```html
    <application-root testVar="hello world"></application-root>
```

After doing lots of research, I decided against using ElementRef to access the attribute, and used Renderer2 instead.  My constructor for my AppComponent is set up as follows:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'application-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
      public data: string;
      constructor(private renderer: Renderer2)
      {
        this.data = this.renderer.selectRootElement('application-root', true).getAttribute('testVar');
      }
      ..
    }
```

When I run this in my application, I get no errors and I get the value "hello world".  However, when I attempt to run a unit test case, I get the following error: 'The selector "application-root" did not match any elements'.  This is my test case:

```js
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          RouterTestingModule,
          HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [
          AppComponent
        ],
        providers: [
          {provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy},
          Renderer2
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      }));
      it('should create the app', () => {
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

Now, if I move my selectRootElement call out of the constructor function, and into the ngOnInit() function, my unit test case passes, but when I try to run the application, I get a blank screen.

What do I need to do in my code to allow me to access a root component attribute that can run correctly in my application and pass a unit test case?

Answer (score 1):

So the solution I came up with was to move everything out of the constructor and into the ngOnInit() function.  When I did a re-test of running the application, it actually worked and nothing was gone from the screen.  However, in order to make this work with the unit test cases, I learned I had to add the element itself in the beforeEach function.

When Angular executes its unit test cases with the AppComponent, the template that gets rendered is a  tag, not the selector that we all know.  So, in order for the application to grab that element, we would have create it first and then set the attributes to that element, so that when the test script runs, it will recognize that element in the template:

```
    let appElement: ElementRef;
    let renderer2: Renderer2;
    describe('AppComponent', () => {
      beforeEach(async(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        imports: [
          RouterTestingModule,
          HttpClientTestingModule
        ],
        declarations: [
          AppComponent
        ],
        providers: [
          {provide: Router, useValue: routerSpy},
          Renderer2
        ]
      }).compileComponents();
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
      renderer2 = fixture.componentRef.injector.get<Renderer2>(Renderer2 as Type<Renderer2>);
      appElement = renderer2.createElement('application-root');
      renderer2.appendChild(fixture.nativeElement, appElement);
      component = fixture.componentInstance;
      }));
      it('should create the app', () => {
        expect(fixture).toBeTruthy();
      });
```

If there is a better way to solve this, I'm all ears.